# Use Angular IO with extern html file (standalone)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm developing a new web project and want to use angular io.

However I need to use it in a html file with elements with custom-attributes like 'data-crawl'. I want to get these and process with it in my angular app.

The html file I will get from my client, so I can't write a own html component for it.

I need to develop a script, that will be included in this html file. The  script will search for the **custom-attributes** in the extern **html-file**.

It is possible, to make this with angular ? So that I develop my functions in TypeScript, write my test etc. in it, export my angular module and finally import this in the html file?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Sony

Comment: It sounds as if you would be working outside the design concepts of Angular. It is not recommended. If you are only dealing with a single HTML file it might be overkill anyway, but there isn't enough info to go on here to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, so angular is not a good option. Thank you